# Send email from excel. After placing body cell content, excel returns "#value!" error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&D8&"?subject="&$D$1&"&cc="&$D$2&"&body="&H8,"Mail It")
```

I am trying to send different questions to different students email. So that I should include question in the body of email. without placing body cell content my cell is working. But after placing the body function in hyperlink formula I getting #value! error.

- "d8:d99" column contains students email id
- "d1" column contain subject name of email
- "d2" column contains cc mail address
- "h8:h99" column is linked to another sheet that contains 10 question in separate rows.

Comment: Did you percent-encode everything?

Answer (score 0):

Swap position of `cc`:
`=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&D8&"?cc="&$D$2&"&subject="&$D$1&"&body="&H8,"Mail it")`